# MySql - Unable to start correctly (0xc0150002)

Tags: mysql, installation

I installed Mysql but when I am trying to login with root user, it is prompting an application error that
**"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). Click Ok to close the application."**

Image is enclosed https://i.stack.imgur.com/abghb.png

I followed some solutions but it doesn't help me.

1. Installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update
2. Reinstalled the Bluetooth drivers.

But it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: No idea but I am sure it can't hurt to specify your OS version and the version of MySQL you want to install (feel free to just say "latest" if you don't care).

Comment: A couple of screenshot would help as well

Comment: Image added @tcadidot0